# Does VLC Player run on multi core machine?

Tags: windows-xp, video, cpu, vlc-media-player

I notice that in the [VLC web page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.0.0.html), it mention that it can:

`With faster decoding on multi-core, GPU, and mobile hardware and the ability to open more formats, notably professional, HD and 10bits codecs, 2.0 is a major upgrade for VLC.`

However, when I play video (those running 720p or 1080p) on a dual core machine, it does not run smoothly and it jerk all the time. It even stop playing the video.

So, is VLC really support multi-core or do I need to have a 6 or 8 core machine in order to play 720p or 1080p HD videos?

Comment: This sounds like it has more to do with your hardware than the software. What CPU/GPU are you using? Also what are the sizes of the videos? Your hard drive may not be reading them fast enough.

Comment: It's a dual core CPU. size of video is 720p and 1080p. probably it might be slow because using 7200rpm hard drive.

Comment: Which OS? What is the CPU model and frequency? You can for example use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to figure this out. How does the CPU graph in the task manager look during playback?

Comment: Windows XP, CPU is 2.6Ghz. CPU Graph is 100% when playing 720p or 1080p.

Comment: @user275517 We need the CPU model, or at least the microarchitecture. "2.6 GHz" means **nothing**. A "2.6 GHz" Pentium 4 (or Pentium D with two cores) is not even a **fifth** as powerful as a Haswell i3 with the same numbers (let's say i3-4130, though that one is actually higher clocked, it's not the clock speed that makes the difference). Judging by the fact you're running XP, an OS that's *over a decade old*, your hardware is probably pretty old too. Even the ancient OS itself could be a hindrance, if you were running on new hardware.